# Verify a jwt token with openresty lua-nginx-module every request

Tags: nginx, lua, jwt

I made react website, that request a remote http API (managed by a third party).
My website is using https with a valide certificate.

- The third party API is "secured" by a simple GET param in the URL , "?key=XXXX" . to check if we can access the endpoint.
- The third party API has CORS

To be able to request the http remote API I made a nginx reverse proxy .
With extra header to allow CORS.
And to secure a little bit more I added JWT Token verification .

All is working fine , if the Header Authorization Bearer with token is invalid or unset i cannot access the third party api. nginx is blocking me.

But as soon as I provide a valid Authorization Header once , any further request will PASS. the token is not checked anymore , even if i make the request from a different device with different IP.

How to check the token for every single request i make

Here is my nginx conf

```
server {
       listen 443 ssl http2;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;


        location / {
            default_type application/json;
            return 200 '{"message": "Endpoint is required"}';
        }

        location  ^~ /api/ {
            include jwt.conf;
            include headers.conf;

           set $args $args&key={KEY};
           proxy_pass http://www.third-party.com/api/;
        }
    }
```

Here is my jwt.conf file , I am using the openresty lua-nginx-module

```
access_by_lua_block {
    local jwt = require "resty.jwt"
    local jwt_obj = jwt:verify("{SECRET}", token, claim_spec)
    local auth_header = ngx.var.http_Authorization

    if auth_header then
        _, _, token = string.find(auth_header, "Bearer%s+(.+)")
    end

    if token == nil then
        ngx.status = ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED
        ngx.header.content_type = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        ngx.say("{\"error\": \"missing JWT token or Authorization header\"}")
        ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED)
    end

     if not jwt_obj["verified"] then
         ngx.status = ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED
         ngx.log(ngx.WARN, jwt_obj.reason)
         ngx.header.content_type = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
         ngx.say("{\"error\": \"" .. jwt_obj.reason .. "\"}")
         ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED)
     end
 }
```

And to be complete , my headers.conf

```
proxy_set_header                X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header                X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

proxy_redirect                  off;
proxy_buffers                   32 16k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size         64k;


if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    return 204;
}

# Ajouter les headers de contrôle d'accès CORS
add_header    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
add_header    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS' always;
add_header    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization' always;
add_header    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

> `_, _, token = string.find(auth_header, "Bearer%s+(.+)")`

you declare `token` as a *global* variable. It is *[strongly discouraged](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#data-sharing-within-an-nginx-worker)*:

> Note that the use of global Lua variables is *strongly discouraged*, as it may lead to unexpected race conditions between concurrent requests.

It explains why subsequent requests are authorized if you do not include the `Authorization` header -- the `token` from the initial request is "cached" in the Lua global state.

Moreover, here:

> `local jwt_obj = jwt:verify("{SECRET}", token, claim_spec)`

you reference the `token` variable *before* it is declared.

The correct code is something like this:

```lua
local jwt = require "resty.jwt"

local auth_header = ngx.var.http_Authorization

-- `local token` is equvalent to `local token = nil`
local token
if auth_header then
    token = string.match(auth_header, "Bearer%s+(.+)")
end

if token == nil then
    ngx.status = ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED
    ngx.header.content_type = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    ngx.say("{\"error\": \"missing JWT token or Authorization header\"}")
    ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED)
end

-- BTW, where do the `claim_spec` come from?
local jwt_obj = jwt:verify("{SECRET}", token, claim_spec)

if not jwt_obj["verified"] then
    ngx.status = ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED
    ngx.log(ngx.WARN, jwt_obj.reason)
    ngx.header.content_type = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    ngx.say("{\"error\": \"" .. jwt_obj.reason .. "\"}")
    ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED)
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much , it works like a charm
I also removed the "claim_spec" , since it was undefined  and unnecessary